# To recieve one record per id and the one with the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table `stamps` with the columns:

- Worker
- Date
- Transferred
- Balance

I want out one row per worker,
the record with the latest day, and also have value 1 in Transferred

I have tried a lot of possibilities but none works the way I want to.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OUT.WORKER,OUT.DATE,OUT.TRANSFERRED,OUT.BALANCE 
FROM ( 
   SELECT WORKER,DATE,TRANSFERRED,BALANCE 
   FROM STAMPS 
   ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS OUT 
GROUP BY WORKER
```

Comment: Can a worker have more one than row for the same date?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: MS SQL 13
There is only one record pr worker and date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want the latest day (presumably the latest for a given worker), so you need the max function.

```
select s.Worker, 
       s.Date, 
      s.Transferred, 
      s.Balance
from 
 (select worker, 
   max(date) as date
   from stamps
   where transferred = 1
   group by Worker) as max_dates,
join stamps s
on s.worked = max_dates.worker
and s.date = max_dates.date
```

Comment: D'oh - you're right, this cannot work properly - will fix my answer .

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to use window functions:

```
SELECT S.WORKER, S.DATE, S.TRANSFERRED, S.BALANCE 
FROM (SELECT S.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WORKER ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM STAMPS S
     ) S 
WHERE SEQNUM = 1;
```

With the right indexes, a correlated subquery often has the best performance:

```
select s.*
from stamps s
where s.date = (select max(s2.date)
                from stamps s2
                where s2.worker = s.worker
               );
```

The appropriate index is on `stamps(worker, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.STAMPS[enter image description here][1]
SELECT subResult.WORKER,
         subResult.Date,
         subResult.Transferred,
         subResult.Balance
FROM
 (
 SELECT WORKER,
        DATE,
        TRANSFERRED,
        BALANCE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Worker ORDER BY date DESC) AS rowNum 
 FROM STAMPS 
 WHERE Transferred=1
) AS subResult
WHERE subResult.rowNum=1
```